# Github actions not picking up changes to build files in non-master branches

Tags: android-ndk, build.gradle, github-actions

When building my android project via a github action, it always fails when the server hosting the action updates it's NDK plugin versions. This requires me to update my versions as well. However, it never seems to be simple.

For example, in a recent update I just made I noticed the NDK version was behind the server. So I downloaded the new version it's using to my local machine and updated the build files (including the local NDK path). After ensuring it builds fine on my local machine, I push to my branch. However, the server still thinks it's trying to build on the old version and fails the build (even though I told the gradle script to use the new version.).

I can successfully make this update on master, is there some reason actions/checkout@v2 doesn't recognize build file updates to non-master branches?

```
Welcome to Gradle 6.1.1!

Here are the highlights of this release:
 - Reusable dependency cache
 - Configurable compilation order between Groovy/Kotlin/Java/Scala
 - New sample projects in Gradle's documentation

For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/6.1.1/release-notes.html

Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)


> Configure project :app
WARNING: Support for ANDROID_NDK_HOME is deprecated and will be removed in the future. Use android.ndkVersion in build.gradle instead.
Support for ANDROID_NDK_HOME is deprecated and will be removed in the future. Use android.ndkVersion in build.gradle instead.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> No version of NDK matched the requested version 21.3.6528147. Versions available locally: 21.4.7075529, 21.4.7075529, 21.4.7075529, 22.1.7171670

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 24s
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```